# Is there an easy free way to apply for all the grants out there or a service?

Tags: funding

I know there are plenty of grants out there but there must be an easier way than filling out form after form online?

Comment: Well, you can pay someone to fill out forms for you and many institutions have administrative staff who helps with writing research proposals. But you always have to tailor your proposal to the specific grant. The answer to the question in the title is: no.

Comment: Not successfully, as they will have different criteria.

Comment: Filling out forms is the smallest part of a grant application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There are no such a services in covering this task. Even if there any, I will not use it since applying for a scholarship require high motivation for a specific position which will not be achieved by automatic filling things. Also, if there any, I will consider them as a harmful service because the experienced professor can differentiate between spam application and real application and this will lead to direct rejection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the answer is: There is no free lunch.

Comment: Well, there are, but you have to apply for them individually.

Comment: On multiple, lengthy forms!